# How to combine duotone effect and CSS mix-blend-mode:difference

Tags: css, gradient, svg-filters, mix-blend-mode

I have a pretty specific case I can't solve here. I'm currently trying to implement a design that relies heavily on gradients and blend modes. What I'm trying to achieve is [this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ3G9.png) where black becomes color 1 and white becomes color 2.

**Edit:** My gradient is not a standard linear or radial gradient. I use different layers with randomly positionned elements to create an *organic* gradient like below. [image: example]

The solution I thought could work was to use an SVG `<feComponentTransfer>` filter to map my B&W range to my two custom colors. It works fine when I apply it to my foreground elements which are in `mix-blend-mode: difference` [(step 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFdip.png) but as soon as I apply it to my B&W gradient background as well, the CSS blending mode picks up the colors and the duotone effect doesn't work anymore. [(step 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTyLf.png)

Any help or suggestion on how to approach the problem would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: The example works as designed - you have the inverse of the gradient in your text - what effect are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simply consider two different gradients, one to color the text and the other for the background.

Here is a basic example:

```css
.container {
  font-size:25px;
  text-align:center;
  background:radial-gradient(circle, red, blue, red);
}

.container > div {
  overflow:auto;
  background:radial-gradient(circle, blue, red, blue);
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  background-clip:text;
  color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1> lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent convallis, risus id accumsan iaculis, ligula ex pellentesque lectus, vel lobortis erat eros in metus. Mauris dignissim malesuada lectus, vel lobortis erat eros in metus. Mauris dignissim malesuada lectus, vel lobortis erat eros in metus. Mauris dignissim malesuada tincidun</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. Maybe it's not clear enough on my screenshots but my background is more complex than just a radial gradient, I built a logic to create an organic gradient... That's why I'm looking into solutions like the one I explained with svg filters. I'll make my question clearer about that.

Comment: @PaulLacour the same trick apply, you create two different background and you apply one on the container and the other one the text

Comment: UUhh nice, I'll look into it :)

Comment: Well it could have worked if CSS element() function was widely supported then I'd have been able to pick my randomly generated custom gradient to use as background but I think I'll have to look for another solution.

Comment: @PaulLacour share your generated gradient in the question and the code you use to generate it